# How do I create an iFrame to put a JS mumble widget on Shivtr?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, widget, dropbox

I used to write passable but simple web pages in HTML years ago and have never touched JS other than copy/paste some content.

I have a clan web page on Shivtr, and a Mumble server with Multiplay.
Multiplay provides a JS widget and the code via [here](http://commsviewer.com/viewers/create).

However Shivtr do not allow JS directly and I've been told (by Shivtr) to ask Multiplay for an iframe version.
Multiplay will not/do not supply this., and also will not provide the URL for the server to use with other widgets.

I have been told that it could be installed by putting the JS in Dropbox and creating an iframe on Shivtr thats simply fetches from Dropbox...

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?
If so, how?

Comment: What's with the line break `<br>` tags?. There's no HTML tags on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What?  I put those in because I wanted it to seperate the points for emphasis.. and the Q page allowed me to put them in...

Comment: Only a limited amount of HTML tags are allowed here, and `<br>` isn't one. It's not a HTML editor, treat it like you would whilst typing an email. Line breaks can be inserted by using `***`.